# Not able to create a React project in eclipse with CodeMix

Tags: eclipse, reactjs

Installed the CodeMix with React Package in eclipse, once create a new React project from the CodeMix Option getting the error "CodeMix could not create the project template because it could not retrieve the corresponding CodeMix pack.[Error Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Bpj.png)"

Comment: I just tried this without seeing the error. Could you check the Extension Manager (go to Help->CodeMix Extensions...) and make sure the React pack is there. Also, check if there is a reload icon at the top right of the extension list, if there is click it. Have you installed other extensions?